# Create Django QuerySet from Oracle table-valued Function

Tags: python, django, oracle

I try to create a Django QuerySet from an Oracle table-valued Function

```
qs = MyModel.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM TABLE(My-table-valued-Function)")
```

As soon as I evaluate the query set I get the error:

> django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Does anybody have a solution for this?

After some debugging I figured out that Django adds a table name to the SQL statement when evaluating the QuerySet including an Oracle table function:

```
XX.objects.raw("SELECT 1 as id, PROJEKT FROM TABLE(my_table_function())")
```

becomes

```
SELECT "CHARTS_XX"."ID", "CHARTS_XX"."PROJEKT" FROM "CHARTS_XX" WHERE     CHARTS_XX"."ID" = %s
```

where "charts" is my app name and "XX" my Model.
Is there any way to force Django to use the table function?

Thanks!
Thorx

Comment: does your django db connection user has permissions for the function?

Comment: Yes, he has. I can use cursor raw. But I need the QuerySet to display values in chartit.

Comment: you can try to look on `print (qs.query)` and execute printed sql in the sqlpplus( or what you use)

Comment: the function's owner and the connection user is the same?

Comment: @Bear Brown 'print(qs.query)' prints the expression I have used in the raw call: 'SELECT * FROM TABLE(My-table-valued-Function)'

Comment: try to connect to database by `./manage.py dbshell` and then run your select.

Comment: @Bear Brown. The select works perfect. The problem is getting a model instance (especially a model property) from the query set. my_instance = qs[0], my_prop = my_instance.my_prop <-this throws the ORA-00942